# Is there a rational solution to the system?

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

[image: A possible rational solution]We have a finite, non-strict order on expressions:
$$a+b+c+d > a+b+c = a+b+d > a+b > \dots$$
Every expression is a sum of a set of variables, there are no constants.
If there is a real solution to the system, can we claim that there is a rational one?

For example, in the picture there is a possible rational solution to the system which represents the paths:
$$a+b > a+c > a > b+c > b > a$$
Can we construct a network with rational distances given a network with real distances?

Thanks!

Comment: Typeset mathematical terms using MathJax. [Here's the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: It's not (to me) clear how the pattern of inequalities/equalities continues. Good if you could formulate in some way to make pattern clear for an arbitrary number of terms.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, I edited the question, hope it is clearer.